# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed with adonisJS

Tags: mysql, adonis.js

Today after trying somes things I wanted to rollback and re create all of my tables and i got this error :

```
❯ error database/migrations/1692713709807_command_products
[ error ]  alter table `command_products` add constraint `command_products_command_id_foreign` foreign key (`command_id`) references `commands` (`id`) - Can't create table `productapi`.`command_products` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
at Packet.asError (K:\DEV\product-api\node_modules\.pnpm\mysql2@3.6.0\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:728:17)
at Query.execute (K:\DEV\product-api\node_modules\.pnpm\mysql2@3.6.0\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26)
at Connection.handlePacket (K:\DEV\product-api\node_modules\.pnpm\mysql2@3.6.0\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:478:34)
at PacketParser.onPacket (K:\DEV\product-api\node_modules\.pnpm\mysql2@3.6.0\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:97:12)
at PacketParser.executeStart (K:\DEV\product-api\node_modules\.pnpm\mysql2@3.6.0\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (K:\DEV\product-api\node_modules\.pnpm\mysql2@3.6.0\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:104:25)
at Socket.emit (node:events:511:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:332:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:305:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:242:10)
```

After some search it look like my table are created in a bad error and cause a foreign key issue. Even after changing the timestamp of my tables the tables are created in a bad order.
Here my migration file from git https://github.com/Nico7522/adonis-api-product/tree/master/database/migrations

If someone can help me, i'm completly lost :/

Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok. Now work. Just I got these line in my user ans adresse tables " table.increments("id").primary()" and I have a foreign key constrain on my user table coming from adresse. So I just removed the primary() from user and all work fine.

Now i wonder, must mandatory create my adresse and then attach the user if the forein key is on the user side ? 

my code "const adresses = (await Adresse.create(adresse)).related('user').create(user)"

Or is there a way to create user before and attach my adresse ?